# Python scikit-learn provide custom training data

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn

I'm starting out using scikit-learn to perform facial recognition. I have tried out the provided example [here](http://scikit-learn.org/dev/auto_examples/applications/face_recognition.html) and works OK. I'm now trying to use my own custom data that consists of images so as to test the facial recognition. I am using the facial database from [here](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/Research/DTG/attarchive:pub/data/att_faces.tar.Z) . I'm now stuck at loading these images to my program as the training set. I'm using the code below to load all the images:

```
    # get the training data


def read_images(path, sz=None):
    """Reads the images in a given folder, resizes images on the fly if size is given.

    Args:
        path: Path to a folder with subfolders representing the subjects (persons).
        sz: A tuple with the size Resizes 

    Returns:
        A list [X,y]

            X: The images, which is a Python list of numpy arrays.
            y: The corresponding labels (the unique number of the subject, person) in a Python list.
    """
    c = 0
    X, y = [], []
    for dirname, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(path):
        for subdirname in dirnames:
            subject_path = os.path.join(dirname, subdirname)
            for filename in os.listdir(subject_path):
                try:
                    im = Image.open(os.path.join(subject_path, filename))
                    im = im.convert("L")
                    # resize to given size (if given)
                    if (sz is not None):
                        im = im.resize(sz, Image.ANTIALIAS)
                    X.append(np.asarray(im, dtype=np.uint8))
                    y.append(c)
                except IOError, (errno, strerror):
                    print("I/O error({0}): {1}".format(errno, strerror))
                except:
                    print("Unexpected error:", sys.exc_info()[0])
                    raise
            c = c+1
    return [X, y]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    if len(sys.argv) < 3:
        print('No image supplied.')
        sys.exit()

    # Now read in the image data. This must be a valid path!
    [X, y] = read_images(sys.argv[1])

    print(len(X), len(y))

    X_train = np.vstack(X)
    print(X_train)
    y_train = np.array(y)

    image_path = sys.argv[2]
    image = np.array(cv2.imread(image_path), dtype=np.uint8)
    if np.ndim(image) == 3:
        image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    image = cv2.equalizeHist(image)
    # create a CLAHE object (Arguments are optional).
    clahe = cv2.createCLAHE(clipLimit=2.0, tileGridSize=(8, 8))
    image = clahe.apply(image)

    # detect face in this image
    detector = FaceDetector()
    X_test = []
    for i, d in enumerate(detector.detect(image)):
        x, y, w, h = d.left(), d.top(), d.right() - \
            d.left(), d.bottom() - d.top()
        a = image[y:(y+h), x:(x+w)]
        b = cv2.resize(a, (130, 130), interpolation=cv2.INTER_CUBIC)
        X_test.append(np.asarray(b, dtype=np.uint8))

    X_test = np.vstack(X_test)

    ##########################################################################
    # Compute a PCA (eigenfaces) on the face dataset (treated as unlabeled
    # dataset): unsupervised feature extraction / dimensionality reduction

    n_components = 150

    print('Extracting the top {} eigenfaces from faces'.format(n_components))
    t0 = time()
    pca = RandomizedPCA(n_components=n_components, whiten=True).fit(X_train)
    print("done in %0.3fs" % (time() - t0))

    print("Projecting the input data on the eigenfaces orthonormal basis")
    t0 = time()
    X_train_pca = pca.transform(X_train)
    **X_test_pca = pca.transform(X_test)**
    print("done in %0.3fs" % (time() - t0))

    ##########################################################################
    # Train a SVM classification model

    print("Fitting the classifier to the training set")
    t0 = time()
    param_grid = {'C': [1e3, 5e3, 1e4, 5e4, 1e5],
                  'gamma': [0.0001, 0.0005, 0.001, 0.005, 0.01, 0.1], }
    clf = GridSearchCV(SVC(kernel='rbf', class_weight='balanced'), param_grid)
    clf = clf.fit(X_train_pca, y_train)
    print("done in %0.3fs" % (time() - t0))
    print("Best estimator found by grid search:")
    print(clf.best_estimator_)

    ##########################################################################
    # Quantitative evaluation of the model quality on the test set

    print("Predicting people's names on the test set")
    t0 = time()
    y_pred = clf.predict(X_test_pca)
    print("done in %0.3fs" % (time() - t0))
```

After this, I also get one test image to run against the above sample:
Line that gives an error is **X_test_pca = pca.transform(X_test)**

The error is:

```
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (130,130) (92,)
```

which I suspect has something to do with my data not being correctly formatted.

Comment: Can you tell us which line is raising the error?  I can't see anything above which would cause this problem.

Comment: I've included my whole code sample

Comment: @Denny -- make sure, both the `trainingDataSET` ( used in **`.fit( X_train_pca, y_train )`** ) and the `testingDataSet` ( used further down the pipeline in `.fit( X_test_pca  )` ) have exactly both the same **`.shape`**-s and colourdepths ( otherwise **`cv2`**-preprocess 'em so as to have ... )

Answer (score 0):

This is because your X_train, which you have used to train your pca i.e. line:

```
pca = RandomizedPCA(n_components=n_components, whiten=True).fit(X_train)
```

, has 92 original columns/features whereas your X_test has 130 features. You manually provide the size of 130 to your test data at this line :

```
b = cv2.resize(a, (130, 130), interpolation=cv2.INTER_CUBIC)
```

once you rectify this you should be fine.